# Shortening a boolean AND with third operand

Tags: binary, bitwise-operators, arithmetic

I'm trying to calculate the sum of 2 bits using basic binary arithmetic and currently, I'm doing this:

```
function Add(bool a, bool b, bool carry)
{
    return
    {
         Result: a ^ b ^ carry,
         Carry: a & b | a & carry | b & carry
    };
}
```

Is there a way to shorten the expression that calculates the `Carry` or I have to manually check all possible combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only a minor simplification:

```
a & b | (a | b) & carry
```

This is equivalent to

```
a & carry | (a | carry) & b
```

and

```
carry & b | (carry | b) & a
```

Comment: That's neat. So, there is no built-in operator (in C language, for that matter) that given 3 operands will yield `true` when at least 2 of the operands are `true`?

Comment: @DumbButterly: No, in C, C++ and Java there is only one operator with three operands (`a ? b : c`) and it does coonditional assignment.

Comment: @DumbButterly C is pretty much a shorthand for assembly and doesn't have anything that you don't find on CPUs.  If it's something you need frequently, write it as a function that can be inlined and any decent compiler will make sure it runs quickly.

Comment: @Blrfl: No, it's an HLL on top of assembler, as anyone who's actually programmed in assembler would readily tell you (I being one). Some of the many things C has that assembler doesn't: loops, functions, structures, types that aren't native-length float or int, type checking, arrays... and so on. And that's just C from circa 2000, which is the last time I used it day in a and day out.

Comment: @LawrenceDol:  You don't have to read far into the introduction of _The C Programming Language_ (1978 edition) to know that (a) Kernighan and Ritchie disagree with your characterization of C as a high-level language and (b) it was designed to reflect the abilities of the processors available at the time.  I'm not implying that C is a 1:1 mapping for assembly does, but rather a shorthand for a lot of the things that were being done by hand in assembly.   If you want to start swinging years of experience around, I've written assembly for about a dozen CPUs since 1980 and learned C in 1987.

Comment: @Blrfl : We can agree to disagree. I wasn't "swinging years of experience around". I was merely calling attention to the fact that I was referring to a dated version of C; it's advanced considerably over the intervening time, making your claim even less true. (Also what I think you really mean is "a superficial abstraction on top of assembler".) As you've programmed in assembler, your claim baffles me even more.

Comment: @Frank Puffer: Nitpick: "a ? b : c" does conditional evaluation, not necessarily conditional assignment. What we do with the expression is up to us.

Answer (score 3):

If you're counting by operations, and you're willing to count `?:` as one operation, then you can improve on [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/342567/44488) with:

`carry ? (a|b) : (a&b)`

That is five operands and three operations.   Or maybe 3.5 operations.   But it's still better than the other answer with 4 operations.

If you're focused on the idea that the function is 'any two or more of the three', this I like this form because it says "If one is high, either of the other two, otherwise both of the other two."

Comment: (You can swap the operands any way you want because the function is symmetric, BTW -- this way takes the fewest characters)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you can add bools in C.  You could add the three bools together and then check if the value is greater than 1.  I doubt this would be a good idea from a performance perspective.  It might be worth considering if you had more than three boolean values and wanted to check if a certain number are set.

I realize this makes no sense for what you want to do specifically but it is a solution for the more general problem of given X bools check if Y (or at least Y) are set.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code for a generic full adder (what you are describing).  Most languages will support this pseudo code.

Using a temporary field means that this will take five operations, two EXCLUSIVE OR, two AND, and one OR.

```
Inputs: a, b, Cin
Outputs: sum, Cout

temp = a XOR b
sum = temp XOR Cin
Cout = (a AND B) OR (temp AND Cin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the booleans to integers and directly compute the result.

```
int sum= (int)a + (int)b + (int)carry;
Result: (bool)(sum & 1);
Carry:  (bool)(sum >> 1);
```